# Read a text file to a string using fortran77

Tags: string, file, text, fortran77

Is it possible to read a text file to a string using fortran77.
I actually have a text file in the following format

```
Some comments
Some comments

n1  m1  comment_with_unknown_number_of_words
..m1 lines of data..

n2  m2  comment_with_unknown_number_of_words
..m2 lines of data..
and so on
```

whereas n1,n2.. are the orders of the objects. m1, m2,..are the number of lines which contains the data about these objects, respectively. I also want to store the comment of each object for further investigations.

How can I deal with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It's a bit tricky to do this in FORTRAN77 which does not have variable-length 'strings'.  Why oh why aren't you writing in a more modern version of Fortran, it's 2013 already ?  Personally I no longer help people write FORTRAN77, it's unethical.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks a lot, I will try to do it. And from which version of fortran can I do it much easier? fortran90?

Comment: From whatever version of Fortran your compiler implements.  Ideally you want a version which implements the varying length character variables which were put into the 2003 standard, having previously been defined in a Technical Report and widely implemented though sometimes in a non-standard fashion.

Comment: @High Performance Mark Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe nobody called me on this.. My apologies this in fact only grabs the first word of the comment...

------------original answer----

Not to recomend F77, but this isnt that tough a problem either. Just declare a char variable long enough to hold your longest comment and use a list directed read.

```
integer m1,n1
char*80 comment

...
read(unit,*)m1,n1,comment
```

If you want to write it back out without padding a bunch of extra spaces thats a bit of effort but hardly the end of the world.

What you can not do at all in f77 is discern whether your file has trailing blanks at the end of a line, unless you go to direct access reading.

------------improved answer

What you need to do is read the whole line as a string then read your integers from the string:

```
read(unit,'(a)')comment
read(comment,*)m1,n1
```

at this point `comment` contains the whole line including your two integers (perhaps that will do the job for you). If you want to pull off the actual string it requires a bit of coding (I have a ~40 line subroutine to split the string into words). I could post if interesed but I'm more inclined as others to encourage you to see if your code will work with a more modern compiler.

Comment: thanks a lot, this helps me so much! I don't want to use f77 either. However the previous model with hundred thousands lines of codes was written in f77 and I am worry that my new version fortran code might not work properly with them..